# Going backwards with RegEx

Tags: .net, regex, parsing, comments, key-value

I need to parse iOS's *.strings files to get key/value pairs with comments.
For example:

```
/* comment */
"key" = "value";
```

Once I have found the line and checked its validity (I already managed to do that) I need to capture it and the comment just before it.

The difficulty is that:

- not every line has a comment before, so I cannot capture the whole block starting with /* and ending with semicolon;
- there may be a comment with line below, but this line could have an invalid format, and so it sould be skipped along with its comment.

So I have to detect the key/value line and then go up for a comment if it exists.

Can RegEx'es go backwards?

P.S. I'm using .NET Framework to parse:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string[] kvp = Regex.Split(line, "\"\\s+?=\\s+?\"");
    if (kvp.Length == 2 && kvp[0].StartsWith("\"") && kvp[1].EndsWith("\";"))
    {
        DataRow row = table.NewRow();
        row["name"] = kvp[0].TrimStart('"');
        row["text"] = kvp[1].Substring(0, kvp[1].Length - 2);
        row["fileId"] = fileId;
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can the comment be more than one line long?

Comment: Theoretically - yes, but I've never found such. In a case of multiline comments I could use string text = File.ReadAllText(fileName); but I can't imagine how do I find all the matches in that case.

Comment: If you do a linewise read why don't you just match `\"(\w+)\"=\"(\w+)\"` and extract the capturing groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do all that in a single regex:

```
Match match = null;
match = Regex.Match(subject, 
    @"(?<=           # Look behind to make sure that there is a comment before:
    (?:              # Try to match...
     /\*             # /*
     (?<comment>     # Capture the comment in the group 'comment'
      (?:            # Match...
       (?!\*/)       # (as long as it's not '*/')
       .             # any character.
      )*             # Repeat as needed.
     )               # End of group 'comment'
     \*/             # Match */
    )?               # Make the whlo comment optional
     \s*             # Match whitespace, including newlines
    )                # End of lookbehind assertion
    ^                # Match the start of the line
    ""               # Match a quote
    (?<name>[^""]*)  # Capture any number of non-quote characters into group 'name'
    ""\s*=\s*""      # Match quote - equals - quote, with optional whitespace
    (?<value>[^""]*) # Capture any number of non-quote characters into group 'text'
    "";              # Match the closing quote and semicolon", 
    RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
row["name"] = match.Groups["name"];
row["text"] = match.Groups["text"];
row["comment"] = match.Groups["comment"];
```

Comment: You'd save yourself a lot of time if you used http://www.regex101.com/ to automatically explain those regexes for you :)

Comment: @Lindrian: Doesn't work: That regex engine doesn't support variable-length lookbehinds. Also, I find that these machine-generated explanations are often not very helpful...

Comment: @Lindrian: Very Nice advice about regex101! Much better than desktop programs! As about the regex itself: key and value may contain escaped characters: \" \= etc.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: You are correct. It uses PHP which does not support variable-length lookbehinds. Despite that though, it does a very good job explaining the regular expressions in my humble opinion. (it would not have any problems explaining it, but since it runs a match simultaneously, you get an error back from php)

Comment: @Paul: Have a look at my regex, it handles escaped values.

Comment: @Lindrian: Sorry, overlooked that.

Comment: @Paul: I've also overlooked something: My first regex always required a comment to be there. Rereading your question, that's not always the case, so I've edited my solution slightly.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Regexes never go backwards, even if you were to do something like `.+$`. But you can make it appear as if they work backwards. However, this is not really necessary for this task.

You can use the following regular expression:

```
/^(?<comment>(?:\/\*(?:(?!\*\/).)*\*\/)?\s*)(?<key>"(?:\\.|[^"])+")\s*=\s*(?<value>"(?:\\.|[^"])+")\s*;/gms
```

(unsure if you need delimiters and the global flag in .net)

So basically, first backreference will hold the comment. The second will hold the key, and the third the value. If you are in every way uninterested in the key/values, the regex can be simplified further by merging the two last backreferences into one.

You now have all the data you want. Just replace accordingly. If the first backreference contains a `null` value you know that there was no comment above that line.

Demo+explanation: http://regex101.com/r/xN1uQ4

Ask away if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can go backwards even set the starting point of the search to look backwards from see: RegexOptions.RightToLeft